# Azure DevOps Deploying IIS to windows server password limit?

Tags: .net, iis, azure-devops, webdeploy

We have an Azure DevOps release pipeline that deploys a .NET website to IIS on a remote server.  Everything was working fine until we changed the password.  The password is correctly changed on the pipeline but for some reason the app pool doesn't get updated properly.  When I input the password manually into the application pool on the server itself, it works fine, but when the pipeline does it, it fails.  The only thing I can think of is that the previous password length was about 10 characters and the new password is much longer.  >35 characters.  Is there a password length limit with Azure DevOps releases?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use a <10 password to check the deploy task? Maybe the task actually has the character limit.

Comment: That's what we had before and it worked fine.  I'm unable to change it back due to company password policies.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if the password begins with a backslsash (\) no matter the length it will fail on deployment, try a different starting character.

Also, there may be other characters causing this, I will edit the post once I have figured out which other characters cause the problem.

As of now, I have successfully used a 39 character password...